# How to get record with diff page number

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get below output:-

Table containt:-

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  word  |  unique id  |  page no  |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  tv    |    4444     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  tv    |    4444     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  tv    |    4444     |     2     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|CDPlayer|    8888     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|CDPlayer|    8888     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  Watch |    1212     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  Watch |    1212     |     2     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to record which are repeated with diff page numbers, i.e if word having same page no then ignore that record and if word having same page no as well as diff page no then collect that record

Output:-

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  word  |  unique id  |  page no  |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  tv    |    4444     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  tv    |    4444     |     2     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  Watch |    1212     |     1     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  Watch |    1212     |     2     |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

Any idea or suggestion, How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one may help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.* FROM mytable m 
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT page_no) OVER (PARTITION BY word,unique_id ) > 1;

+-------+-----------+---------+
| WORD  | UNIQUE_ID | PAGE_NO |
+-------+-----------+---------+
| tv    |      4444 |       1 |
| tv    |      4444 |       2 |
| Watch |      1212 |       1 |
| Watch |      1212 |       2 |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

QUALIFY: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html

Comment: I need to add where condition as well (where flag= false)
According to document I guess we have only option of group by clause

Comment: can you update your sample data and output?

Comment: Working properly with few changes in your query